# Something from with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

When i coding Java in eclipse not all code working. Sometimes i've got an error even if code is correct, but when i turn off Clear Type then looks like everything working just fine. Why is that and is it possible coding without turning off Clear Type ?

Comment: Which version of eclipse you are using?

Comment: Under the `clean` option there is a option called `Build Automatically`. Check that.

Comment: You can try posting your code also and telling us which part gets highlighted..

Comment: If you compile the program and you don't see any errors under the `problems` tab, you're fine. Sometimes eclipse gets a little confused. Suresh Atta's suggestion would work, or sometimes you can close and reopen the tab.

Comment: I'm using Kepler. Like i sad my code is correct, but when i run it it's says 'unknow source' and etc. But when i turn on CLEAR TYPE in my computer when program works just fine

Comment: I *highly* doubt ClearType has anything to do with this.

Comment: ClearType as I know the term is a font rendering system on Microsoft Windows. What do *you* mean when you say CLEAR TYPE?